# How can i add new Routes to API Platform

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com

i started using API Platform together with Symfony and i don't know how to add a route, can anybody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

its quite simple..
You first create your Entity like

```
php bin/console Make:Entity
```

and then you just have to add some decorator to it like this

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 */

Please read this starter guide which should help you with your question:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/getting-started/

Comment: ah great, sorry i don't know how i missed this guide.
Thanks, i will mark as answer